# Is it fine to ask a question about how a data structures/algorithm question solution works on SO? Or any recommendation for another SE site

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There are plenty of algorithms which are not intuitive and difficult to understand.

I see plenty of solutions for algorithms online, some of which look remarkable and I don't have an answer to how the different solutions work.

Is Stack Overflow a good place to ask about the solutions by others specifically on problem solving?

Will it be received well?

Or is there any other SE community which is better to ask such a question?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Not a duplicate, asking for code explanation is too general. DS/ALGO gets negative responses IMO but just asking for a code snippet or some module/function etc explanation may be entirely different. One has a negative response and the other is easily answered. The reason for the question is specifically to figure if its okay to post on SO which might be perceived differently. I could post what is best understood by me about the Algo solution but still get negative responses

Comment: Related: *[Standard for machine learning questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380942/)*, *[How can I ask a good question on machine learning (ML)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399477/)*, and *[Do pure "machine learning" questions belong to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291009/)*.

Comment: What site such a question would best fit on would really depend on the nature of the question.  As is said on the duplicate, if you just post some solution to a problem and ask, "how does this work" that'll be a bad question.  If you have a more specific question about some more specific thing about the solution you don't understand, what site that would go on would depend on what that more specific question is.  If it's about how it's programming, it could belong on SO, if it's more conceptual about the domain of the program, there might be a better site.  Without more info it's hard to say.

Comment: @Servy Its not about programming here, but about complex algorithms which may have taken years to develop. For instance Manachers Algorithm. Even Binary Search was developed after years of research. Can someone not ask how does an algorithm work or some new approach which hasn't been named yet as an alternative to manachers algoritm or something coded differently. Simply asking a code piece could mean something else entirely like explain working of context manager etc but even that would have good responses but not an algorithm.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Updated the Question DS meant Data Structures not Data Science. ML Algorithms and Problem Solving Algorithms can be classified separately. Also ML algo is treated differently on SO. But Problem Solving Algo questions have negative responses.

Comment: @AkshayHazari If you just want someone to explain the entirety of some algorithm, or provide some novel algorithm equivalent but superior to some other, then either of those questions would be way too broad, as the duplicate is telling.  Again, if you have a *specific* question, it's possible that there would be a site it's appropriate on, but again, what site it is would depend on the nature of the question.  Since it seems you don't have any more specific question in mind and just want an algorithm explained "in general", it seems the duplicate gives you your answer.

Comment: @Servy I had encountered a different solution to Manachers algorithm but it looked very simple. And it has been used by many. There is no explanation to it anywhere I've searched though. And I had been asked this in an interview recently which having given a DP solution, was even not enough to the interviewer. He wanted to me to reduce the space complexity associated with the DP solution. Having asked for the explanation on other sites like Leetcode, doesn't really get you an answer. And on SO it gets downvoted.

Comment: @AkshayHazari "Reduce the space complexity of this approach", or even "is it possible to provide a solution with similar time complexity and lower space complexity" does seem a bit broad to me, but perhaps not unredeemably so.  It sounds like your question is more theoretical, and not practical, so Stack Overflow doesn't seem like an ideal choice.   I'm tempted to suggest the computer science site, but as I have no experience with the site itself, so perhaps ask on that sites meta if such a question would be appropriate, or if/how it could be appropriately structured.

Comment: @Servy My question is not about reducing space complexity of an algorithm that was what the interviewer asked me to do. I searched this after the interview found the solution expected during interview was Manachers algorithm, and figured there are plenty of solutions to Manachers algorithm, one of them looks fairly simple and works, but there is no explanation to it. I thought of adding it to multiple forums to get an explanation, but no one has answered yet.